# react-doc-viewer won't show Docx file, shows blank

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to use DocViewer in reactjs to display docx file which is hosted over the internet, it gives me some blank page , checking over the internet i have since not been able to see and understand why this is so

My code is looking thus :

```
import "./App.css";
import DocViewer, {DocViewerRenderers} from "react-doc-viewer";

function App() {
  const doc = [{ uri: "https://docproc.bsite.net/Doc1.docx" }];
  return (
    <div className="App">
      return <DocViewer pluginRenderers={DocViewerRenderers} documents={doc} />;
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Kindly advice, this is the first time doing something like this

Answer (score 0):

Adding a File type worked for me,
{
uri: require("./Dynamic_tabs.docx"),
fileType: 'docx'
},

Answer (score 0):

docs wont work due to the issue in package however you can show pdf files will render properly you can also use this code

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>My Website</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
    <link rel="icon" href="./favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
  </head>
  <body>
    <main>
        <iframe
          id='id12321'
          title='dummy'
          width="100%"
          height="800"
          frameborder="0"
          src='https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=https://calibre-ebook.com/downloads/demos/demo.docx&embedded=true'
        ></iframe>
    </main>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

After several hours of work I realized that we are being deceived by the property: pluginRenderers={DocViewerRenderers}
waiting for it to define the typing for the uri documents, but that doesn't happen! and the solution I found is to import the necessary types directly from DocViewerRenderers in this way:

`import PDFRendererfrom "./pdf";` 
and using fileType of documents:

```
            documents={[
              {
                uri: yourUrl
                fileType: PDFRenderer),
              },
            ]}
```

If you want to use more than one type, you can do it this way:

```
const supportedFileTypes = ["pdf", "png", "docx"];

  const getFileType = (fileName: string) => {
    const extension = fileName.split('.').pop()?.toLowerCase();
    return supportedFileTypes.includes(extension!) ? extension: 'default';
  };
```

and use in fileType:

```
            documents={[
              {
                uri: yourUrl
                fileType: getFileType(yourUrl),
              },
            ]}
```

version:  "@cyntler/react-doc-viewer": "1.14.0",

Answer (score 0):

##### The docx file MUST be a publicly accessible url.

**Local files will NOT work** because the docx renderer (which uses an external service) needs to be able to access the url.

```
import DocViewer, { DocViewerRenderers } from "@cyntler/react-doc-viewer";

function App() {

return (
    <div style={{ height: "100vh", width: "100vw" }}>
      <DocViewer
        documents={[{ uri: "http://your-publicly-accessible-url.docx", fileType: "docx" }]}
        pluginRenderers={DocViewerRenderers}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

**I found this GitHub issue very helpful** [Docx not working GitHub Issue](https://github.com/Alcumus/react-doc-viewer/issues/72)